# What is the meaning of ::class.java

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit2

I am trying to access the web api through Retrofit2 so I have created a builder for that in which I don't understand what is this line doing how I am able to pass my interface in that

```
 val retrofitBuilder = Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .build()

                //meaning of this line
                **.create(ApiInterface::class.java)**
```

Here is the Interface

```
interface ApiInterface {

    @GET("users")
    fun getData():Call<List<FakeJsonDataItemItem>>

}
```

what am I passing in there?

Answer (score 6):

By using `::class.java`, you get an instance of Class.
It is Java Reflection API.

If you want to get Java class reference, you have to use .java property on a KClass instance:

```
val c = ExampleClass::class.java  // reference type of java
```

And by using `::class`, you get an instance of KClass. It is Kotlin Reflection API.
When we create an object using any class type as below the reference type will be type of KClass.

```
val c = ExampleClass::class  // reference type of KClass
```

Retrofit `create()` method behind the scene validates the interface. After that, if the interface is validated an API interface instance is created using Retrofit, the instance returned from retrofit is actually a proxy class, a dynamic implementation of the interface at runtime.

Comment: here instance means the object of that class??

Answer (score 0):

`Class` objects basically describe a particular type, like a `Class<String>` is a special object that describes the `String` class.

They contain [useful information](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classModifiers.html) like what fields that type has, what methods it has etc. That might be what your Retrofit call is doing - taking an interface definition, looking at what methods are defined on it (and important annotations and whatever else), and generating some code that matches it.

A really common use of `Class` objects is as a type definition that you can pass around and refer to. You see it a lot in generic functions.

They also let you create instances of that type, by calling [`getConstructor()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor(java.lang.Class...)) and then `newInstance()` - this can be useful if you want to say "here's the type of object I want you to create" without hardcoding specific constructor calls for each type. You could (for example) create a function that creates and displays `Fragment`s in Android, which you call by passing in the `Class` of a fragment type, and let the function invoke the default constructor and create an instance whenever it's appropriate.

---

In Kotlin, instead of `MyClass.class` you call `MyClass::class` ​- but that gives you a `KClass` object, which is a Kotlin version of `Class` which some Kotlin-specific extras (things like whether it's a `data class`, etc).

If you want the equivalent Java `Class` object (which most libraries will be using unless they're Kotlin-specific) you call the `java` property on the `KClass`, i.e. `MyClass::class.java`, which gives you the `Class<MyClass>` object
​